# Is it possible to group my Craft plugins using the PSR-0 Standard?

Tags: plugin-development

I'd like to group my Craft plugins using the PSR-0 Standard, I was hoping I could use the following:

```
CompanyName_PluginNamePlugin extends BasePlugin

plugins/
    companyname/
       pluginname/
           CompanyName_PluginNamePlugin.php
```

Is it possible to group plugins in sub folders? Or do I just need to prefix my plugin folder - eg:

```
plugins/
   companyname_pluginname/
       CompanyName_PluginNamePlugin.php
```

This gets messy if I want to group any further:

```
plugins/
    companyname_pluginname
    companyname_subgroup_otherpluginname
    companyname_secondsubgroup_otherpluginname
```

Thanks,

Phil.

Answer (score 1):

Craft plugin naming conventions follow a specific format.

[The plugin folder must live immediately under the `craft/plugin` folder and it must be the all lowercase name of your plugin's handle.](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up#create-your-plugins-folder)

Your [primary plugin class](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up#create-your-plugins-folder) must live immediately in that folder and is named after your plugin's handle plus the word "Plugin".  i.e. `PluginHandlePlugin`.

Craft doesn't support any concept of multiple primary plugin class files in one plugin folder.